# Nginx rewrite properly quoted ampersand in values causing problem

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am trying to rewrite some urls with following nginx rewrite rule

```
rewrite ^/some\/url\/(.*)\/$ /some/url/?filter=$1;
```

Rewriting does not seem to work if a query contains an `&` e.g.

```
?filter=key:abcd & efgh
```

which I am quoting properly to

```
?filter=abcd%20%26%20N%20efgh
```

My problem is only rewritten url `/som/url/key:abcd%20%26%20N%20efgh` do not work. If I access it like `/some/url/?filter=abcd%20%26%20N%20efgh` it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: I had similar problems with apache's mod_rewrite.  I think there's some amount of url-decoding done before rewrite rules are processed.  In the end, I had to pass the raw URL to PHP, and parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I was using an old version of the nginx(7.6) and the problem was solved by upgrading to the latest stable release(1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Putting URL you want to rewrite to another "location" could solve your problem.
(I suppose in location directive nginx doesn't do any escaping)
So for your example it would be:

```
location /some/url/ {
 if ($uri ~* ^/some/url/(.*)$
 {
   rewrite ^.*$ /some/url/?filter=$1 break;
 }
 proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 #proxy_set... <- and other proxy related things
}
```

at least it worked for me(in my case even question marks were replaced with "%3f".
Excerpt from official documentation "Note that the $args variable is not decoded, unlike URIs during location matching." http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule